# Angular Material Autocomplete and API Objects

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular9

I'm fighting with Material's Autocomplete for several days. I've used tons of examples from here, and still can't get it work.
What I want to achieve is get Users from API, load them to autocomplete as the name should be visible but I want a value as object.
This is what I've got till now:

```
***API Service:***

export class UserService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  }
}

***component.ts***

constructor(private usc: BreweryService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.users = this.usc.getData();
    
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      myControl: ['', Validators.required],
      name: ['', Validators.required]
    });
 
    this.filteredUsers = this.form.controls['myControl'].valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(val => {
        return this.filter(val || '')
        
      })
    )    
}

filter(val: string) {
  return this.users.pipe(
    map(response => response.filter(option => {
      return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
    }))
  )
}

displayFn(user): string {
  return user.name;
}

***html***
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-label>Assignee</mat-label>
  <input type="text" matInput formControlName="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" 
  [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | async" 
        [value]="user">
      <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>  
</mat-form-field>
```

The console throws error:

"ERROR TypeError: val.toLowerCase is not a function"

and autocomplete not working on typing.

I've created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-battle) to show the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```
  myControl = new FormControl();
```

After

```
this.filteredUsers = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(""),
  map(value => (typeof value === "string" ? value : value.name)),
  map(name => (name ? this.filter(name) : this.users.slice()))
);
```

Check if this.users is not empty and return list of object with name in

And be sure filteredUsers is Observable

```
filter(val: string) {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();
    return this.users.filter(
      option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0
    );
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: No, it's not working. i cannot use filter, slice on Observables, And i'm using  ReactiveForms

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you choose one option, your function gets the whole object into `val` (You can see in the console the last print before the error), then `val` is not a string and you get `"ERROR TypeError: val.toLowerCase is not a function"`.
You should change your return code statement as follows:

```
 return val === "string" ? option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0 : val;
```

see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-battle-fujdun?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).